# How to dynamically change the name of column in the sqlstatement to be used for retrieving data using a combobox

Tags: mysql, vb.net, combobox

I want to dynamically change the name of the column in my sqlstatement every time I select an item name similar of the columns on the cmbcategory comboBox. Then use it to get its data to be transferred to the cmbparts comboBox. Is it possible?

This is my sample code:

```
    Public Sub cmbpartfill()

        sqlstatement = "select '" & cmbcategory.Text & "' from tblparts"
        Connect()
        command = New MySqlCommand(sqlstatement, connection)
        reader = command.ExecuteReader
        While reader.Read
            cmbpart.Items.Clear()
            cmbpart.Items.Add(reader.Item(0).ToString)
        End While
        Disconnect() 

    End Sub
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This will work I think...............

```
sqlstatement = "select " & cmbcategory.Text & " from tblparts"
```

Edited:
 Just try i am not sure............

```
sqlstatement = "select [" & cmbcategory.Text & "] from tblparts"
```

Comment: It worked Sir! Thank you very much. :) But still the reader does not accept column names with spaces. Is there a way to make the reader accept the columns' names with spaces?

Answer (score 0):

Use a **backticks** "`" instead of **Single Quotes** "'".

```
sqlstatement = "select `" & cmbcategory.Text & "` from tblparts"
```